# Logging/monitoring all function calls from an application

Tags: c++, debugging

we have a problem with an application we're developing. Very seldom, like once in a hundred, the application crashes at start up. When the crash happens it brings down the whole system, the computer starts to beep and freezes up completely, the only way to recover is to turn off the power (we're using Windows XP). The rarity of the crash combined with the fact that we can't break into the debugger or even generate a stackdump when it occurs makes it extremely hard to debug.

I'm looking for something that logs all function calls to a file. Does such a tool exist? It shouldn't be impossible to implement, profilers like VTune does something very similar.

We're using visual studio 2008 (C++).

Thanks

A.B.

Answer (score 4):

For Visual C++ [_penter() and _pexit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx) can be used to instrument your code.

See also [Method Call Interception in C++](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/logandtracefiles/article.php/c11065/).

Answer (score 4):

Logging function entries/exits is a low-level approach to your problem. I would suggest using automatic debugger instrumentation (using Debugger key under Image File Execution Options with regedit or using gflags from the package I provide a link to below) and trying to repro the problem until it crashes. Additionally, you can have the debugger log function call history of suspected module(s) using a script or have collect any other information.
But not knowing the details of your application it is very hard to suggest a solution. Is it a user app, service or a driver? What does "crashes at startup" mean - at windows startup or app's startup?
Use this [debugger package](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.Mspx) to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a second machine as a remote debugger (via the network)? When the application (and system) crashes, the second machine should still show some useful information, if not the actual point of the problem. I believe VC++ has that ability, at least in some versions.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with the logging idea is that when the system crashes, the latest log entries might still be in the cache and have no chance to be written to disk...

If it was me I would try running the program on a different PC - it might be flaky hardware or drivers causing the problem. An application program "shouldn't" be able to bring down the system.

Answer (score 2):

A few Ideas-
There is a good chance that just prior to your crash there is some sort of exception in the application. if you set you handler for all unhandled exceptions using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() and write a stack trace to your log file, you might have a chance to catch the crash in action.
Just remember to flush the file after every write.

Another option is to use a tool such as [strace](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=Strace.htm) which logs all of the system calls into the kernel (there are multiple flavors and implementations for that so pick your favorite). if you look at the log just before the crash you might find the culprit

Answer (score 1):

GCC (including the version [MingGW for Windows development](http://www.mingw.org/)) has a code generation switch called [-finstrument-functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-finstrument_002dfunctions-1914) that tells the compiler to emit special calls to functions called __cyg_profile_func_enter and __cyg_profile_func_exit around every function call.  For Visual C++, there are similar options called [/GH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y(VS.71).aspx) and [/Gh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h(VS.71).aspx).  These cause the compiler to emit calls to __penter and __pexit around function calls.

These instrumentation modes can be used to implement a logging system, with you implementing the calls that the compiler generates to output to your local filesystem or to another computer on your network.

If possible, I'd also try running your system using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or a similar checking tool.  This might catch your problem before it gets out-of-hand.